# tcpdf giving ERROR, Saying : TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Tags: php

When I click on button to create PDF its giving error saying :

> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

i have included library also;

```
include ("tstcpdf/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');

    $html = '<html>
                <head>
                <title>Insurance Certificate</title>
                <style>
                body{
                    font-family : Calibri;
                }
                table{
                table-layout: fixed;
                }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table width="500px" height="600px" border="0"> 
                    <tr>
                            </tr>
                    <tr>

                    </tr><br /><br />
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertically-align:middle; font-size:14px;"><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br />
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-size:14px;" ><b><u></u></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-size:12px;"><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="font-size:10px;">.</td>
                    </tr><br />
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold">:</td>
                            <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['cus_name'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['addrs1'].', '.$getdetails['addrs2'].', '.$getdetails['city'].', '.$getdetails['pin'].'</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['mobile'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['email'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['product'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['date_time'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['imei'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['pur_priz'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['invoice_no'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC">
                        <td width="240px" style="font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td width="300px">'.$getdetails['policy'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br/><br/>
                <table bgcolor="#EAEBEC" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 538px;">
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;"><b></b></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;"><b>:</b></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;"><b>    :</b></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;"><b>    :</b></td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; font-size:10px;">--</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>        
</html>';

 //echo $html;
 ob_end_clean(); 
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false,'');
  $pdf->lastPage();
  $pdf->Output(); 
  ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Just a guess, shouldn't you be using `ob_start()` before the `$pdf->writeHtml()` ?

Comment: ob_start() is also not working....